# How to import "crypto" system library in NodeJS because it is suddenly undefined?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, cryptojs

I updated a NestJS based project from 2021 that contains an import like this:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
```

Nowadays, with Node 18, `crypto` is undefined.

What happened to this lib, and is there a replacement available? According to [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html), this actually should not happen to be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try importing via `node:crypto`. The `node:` namespace is something new with ESM. If this isn't an ESM project and just NestJS + Typescript, then you can try `import * as crypto from 'crypto'` or try setting `syntheticDefaultImports: true` in the `tsconfig`. Note, that setting is already set to true if `esModuleInterop` is set to `true`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  esModuleInterop: true was the best approach here for nestJS+TS.